# Object matrix = Array - what is wrong with array reflection tutorial on Oracle's website example

Tags: java, reflection, multidimensional-array

I am trying to follow [this array reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arraySetGet.html) on Oracle's website which doesn't seem to work. Being that this is Oracle's own documentation, I am just wondering if I am doing anything wrong:

```
Object matrix = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2);
Object row0 = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2);
Object row1 = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2);

Array.setInt(row0, 0, 1);
Array.setInt(row0, 1, 2);
Array.setInt(row1, 0, 3);
Array.setInt(row1, 1, 4);

Array.set(matrix, 0, row0); // <- This throws IllegalArgumentException
Array.set(matrix, 1, row1);
```

Now, I know in Java 2d arrays are basically just nested arrays, so in theory it should work. Am I missing anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess code is wrong at oracle site

It should be

```
   Object matrix = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2, 2);
```

The code

```
   Object matrix = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2);
```

creates a array of of size 2, but array objects must be **int.class.**

Full code be:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class CreateMatrix {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Object matrix = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2, 2);//var arg was wrong in docs?
        Object row0 = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2);
        Object row1 = Array.newInstance(int.class, 2);

        Array.setInt(row0, 0, 1);
        Array.setInt(row0, 1, 2);
        Array.setInt(row1, 0, 3);
        Array.setInt(row1, 1, 4);

        Array.set(matrix, 0, row0);
        Array.set(matrix, 1, row1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                out.format("matrix[%d][%d] = %d%n", i, j, ((int[][]) matrix)[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would 1 argument `2` just mean it's a 1 dimension array with 2 indices?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis : yes, it becomes a array of size 2, with integer storage